# Glitch while unpacking the attribute names and coefficients

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

This isn't actually an error that is thrown as much as a glitch I don't understand.

```
list(zip(X_train_select.columns, lr_mod.coef_))
```

I use this line to show me the coefficients of a model along with the name of the features, after training a model using sklearn, to understand which feature is of more importance and which plays a very little role in making predictions.

```
[('onnet_mou_8',
  array([-0.66702875, -0.36908825, -0.62763428,  0.55019987,  0.42000536,
          0.23324475, -0.34923   , -0.53591227, -0.51666227, -0.20964182,
          0.16327186,  0.30434683,  0.17354234, -0.6427968 ,  0.04148923,
         -0.39615   ,  0.2321794 , -0.2989932 , -0.2238154 , -0.32478291,
         -0.3414018 ,  0.51018786, -0.10059598, -0.38008471]))]
```

This is the output I'm getting. I don't understand why I'm not getting a full-fledged output.

I've tried converting the data type of feature columns to a NumPy array, tried to attack this issue by trying to plot a feature importance graph, and a few more things. I got different types of errors for all those different methods and I'm back to inspecting why this isn't working properly.

```
Index(['onnet_mou_8', 'offnet_mou_8', 'roam_ic_mou_8', 'roam_og_mou_8',
       'loc_og_t2t_mou_8', 'std_og_t2t_mou_8', 'loc_ic_t2t_mou_8',
       'loc_ic_t2m_mou_8', 'spl_ic_mou_8', 'total_rech_num_8',
       'total_rech_amt_6', 'total_rech_amt_7', 'total_rech_amt_8',
       'last_day_rch_amt_8', 'max_rech_data_7', 'av_rech_amt_data_8',
       'vol_2g_mb_6', 'vol_2g_mb_8', 'monthly_2g_8', 'total_6', 'total_7',
       'avg_of_6_7', 'arpu_8-7', 'loc_ic_8-7'],
      dtype='object')
```

These are my features.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the shape/type of `lr_mod.coef_`?

Comment: The shape of the coefficients was 1, 22. I reshaped it to get it to display the way I wanted. Thank you!